# Android keyboard not opening for input tag bound to touchstart

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Markup:

```
<section id="loginform">
  <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <input type="submit" value="login" id="login"/>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#loginform #username').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
   $(this).focus()
})
$('#loginform #password').bind('touchstart', function() {
   $(this).focus()
})
```

Opening this site on Android (4.0) and clicking in the input-field for username or password, no keyboard pops up... If I do some code like this:

```
$('#loginform #username').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    alert("android why u no keyboard show!?")
    $(this).focus()
})
```

Then the keyboard will pop up... Alerting `e.isDefaultPrevented()` returns `false`

Any idea of what can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this: you can place this code in `document.ready` or some where else too

```
$('#username').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
   $(this).focus()
})
$('#password').bind('touchstart', function() {
   $(this).focus()
})
```

May be there is some event bubbling going on with in it.

Comment: Didn't work... :( Wonder why the alert() is helping, if I put that there the keyboard pops up...

Comment: I think try adding some time interval delay that will help this to work like settimeout function. go over this link http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/